# Estimating amount of files in a 100GB Hadoop Filesystem

Tags: java, file, hadoop, filesystems, heap-memory

I'm trying to estimate how many files (or INodes) can be stored in a Hadoop Filesystem with a NameNode of 100 GB.

```
abstract class INode implements Comparable<byte[]> {
    protected byte[] name;
    protected INodeDirectory parent;
    protected long modificationTime;
    protected long accessTime;
}

public class BlockInfo extends Block implements LightWeightGset.LinkedElement {
    private LightWeightGset.LinkedElement nextLinkedElement;
    private Object[] triplets;
}
```

It's assumed that the ratio blocks per INode is 1.5:1. It's also assumed that each block has 3 replicas. In addition to these two classes theres a BlocksMap class which holds a reference to all blocks in the cluster. **How many INodes can be stored on the heap of the NameNode?**

So far I've calculated that the class INode requires ~N bytes and BlockInfo ~24M where N is the length of the byte array `name` and M is the amount of blocks. How do I continue?

Comment: What do you mean by "NameNode of 100 GB" do you mean it has 100GB of memory because memory matters more than disk space on a NameNode and how much metadata the NameNode can keep in memory at once determines the number of files it can keep track of. The data itself is actually stored on the DataNodes (slave nodes). Can you please clarify what you are after?

Comment: I'll try to clarify. I am to assume a NameNode JVM capacity of 100 GB. Given a ratio of Inodes to Blocks of 1.5 and assuming 3 Replicas of each Block, how many Inodes can fit on the heap of the NameNode’s JVM?